# Tomcat context.xml files, is there a hierarchy?

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, symlink, context.xml

I am trying to use symbolic links in one of the applications I have running on Tomcat5.  Thanks to some help from [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315093/configure-symlinks-for-single-directory-in-tomcat) I was able to do it 
 by creating a context.xml file in

/...myapplication/META-INF/context.xml

I am now trying to implement this on a production server.  However, there are other applications running on it.  And there is another context file

/...tomcat/conf/context.xml

It seems to me these are setting configurations server-wide to all applications.  If I allowLinks in the conf/context.xml file, my symbolic links work.  If I don't allowLinks in conf/context.xml, my application's symbolic links do not work, even though I have allowed them in the META-INF/context.xml

My question is, does the conf/context.xml control all applications?  If I want symbolic links to work only in one application, do I need to remove the conf/context.xml and create new context files for each application?  Or is there a way I can allow symbolic links in myapplication only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322260/which-tomcat-5-context-file-takes-precedence#322535) to the "[Which Tomcat 5 context file takes precedence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322260/which-tomcat-5-context-file-takes-precedence)" question.

Regarding your specific `allowLinks` question, the value in `conf/context.xml` takes precedence by default.  If you say nothing in your `conf/context.xml`, the default value is [`allowLinks="false"`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html#Standard%20Implementation) in your `conf/context.xml`.

If you want to change it only for your `myapplication`, trying to say `<Context allowLinks="true" ...>` in your `META-INF/context.xml` will have no effect because *normally* the `conf/context.xml` setting will take precedence.

But, if you say  `<Context allowLinks="true" override="true" ...>`  in your `META-INF/context.xml`, then all your `<Context>` settings in `META-INF/context.xml` will be **highest** precedence, overriding anything in `conf/context.xml`.

Finally, instead of a `myapplication/WEB-INF/context.xml` file, I recommend using a `conf/Catalina/localhost/myapplication.xml` file.  This technique means you can keep the contents of your WEB-INF clean, which is the guts of your webapp -- I don't like to risk mucking about in the guts of my webapp. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a point.

Usually th meta-inf/context.xml is copied to the conf/Catalina/localhost/myapplication.xml

When redploying a war file the conf/Catalina/localhost/myapplication.xml is deleted and a new one copied in as described above.

This can be a real pain. I like the idea of application specific context but I fail to see how having this in the meta-inf directory helps.

For Prod, UAT, etc this becomes a real pain.

So for anything server static but application specific it is better to put it in the conf/context.xml. Which has the negative that it holds context for several applications, touch one you inadvertently touch them all.

Comment: This is not true.  Straight from the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html): _Once this file exists, it will not be replaced if a new WAR with a newer /META-INF/context.xml is placed in the host's appBase._