# Which Tomcat 5 context file takes precedence?

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, settings, context.xml

[Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/deployer-howto.html) says:

The locations for Context Descriptors are;

$CATALINA_HOME/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/context.xml
$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/[webappname]/META-INF/context.xml

On my server, I have at least 3 files floating around:

```
1 ...tomcat/conf/context.xml
2 ...tomcat/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml
3 ...tomcat/webapps/myapp/META-INF/context.xml
```

What is the order of precedence?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For the files you listed, the simple answer assuming you are using all the defaults, the order is (note the **conf**/Catalina/localhost):

```
...tomcat/conf/context.xml
...tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml
...tomcat/webapps/myapp/META-INF/context.xml
```

I'm basing this (and the following discussion) on the [Tomcat 5.5 official documentation for the **Context Container**](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html).

So if that's the simple answer, whats the complete answer?

Tomcat 5.5. will look in a couple of other places for `<Context>` elements beyond those you've listed (see the official docs).

The `META-INF/context.xml` will never be opened if Tomcat finds a `Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml`.  So if you actually have all the files above, its more correct to say the the `META-INF/context.xml` is **irrelevant**, not that it's the lowest precedence.

If you say `<Context override="true" ...>` in your `Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml` that will make it the **highest** precedence, regardless of `conf/context.xml`. Same thing in your `META-INF\context.xml`, as long as you don't have a `Catalina/localhost/myapp.xml` (see previous paragraph).

Also, the `/Catalina/localhost/` portion of the path in the files above actually comes out of the "default" `conf/server.xml` and matches the `<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">`.  If your `server.xml` uses different values for `name` and `defaultHost` in the `<Engine>`, that's the dir structure where Tomcat will look.

Finally, for the `...tomcat\` portion of the files you listed, Tomcat uses the dir from the `$CATALINA_BASE` environment variable.  If that's not set, then it uses the dir from the `$CATALINA_HOME` environment variable, which is the directory of the Tomcat installation.  I like to set and use `$CATALINA_BASE` so that I don't "pollute" my Tomcat installation.

Comment: Wow, a very detailed and impressive answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is:

- tomcat/conf/context.xml is the "default" context.xml whose contents are overlayed with the webapp context definitions.  My TC 5 default context.xml has almost nothing in it, other than listing the web.xml as a watched resource, which supports this notion.
- tomcat/Catalina//.xml is used for the webapp.  Either it is place here manually, or is taken from your webapp *at deployment time*...so this is the real master that TC uses.  If you edit this changes will be read next start.
- tomcat/webapps/myapp/META-INF/context.xml - this is copied to tomcat/Catalina/ upon *initial deployment*  if you alter this after initial deployment, I don't think that has any effect

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any official documentation, but I have observed the load order to be:

```
1 tomcat_home/conf/context.xml
2 tomcat_home/webapps/myapp/META-INF/context.xml
```

Where #2 is the last one applied (so its settings override all previous ones, where applicable).

I have never used the webapp named context files (your option #2).