# Realm Resource and context.xml in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I'm looking for a little clarification on JNDI Realms vs Resources.

I have a **LDAP** realm and a **Database Resource** in my application.  They currently reside in `META_INF/contex.tml`, with a `<resource-ref>` in `web.xml` pointing to the resource.

I'm attempting to move both of these items into tomcat and out of my application.

On linux I placed both the `<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"....` and the `<Resource name="UserDatabase"....` in the `$CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml` and everything "seems" to work fine, however, I'm not sure this is the correct way to do this.

When I tried a similar setup on the mac tomcat seems to freakout and goes into a mode where it continually prompts me for my password on the manager GUI which implies something very bad may have happened.

What is the best practice and best "location" for moving these resources out of my local application - and do i need to do anything in `web.xml` to tell it to "look up" these resources from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat's configuration files are general and valid for all applications (unless you restrict some of their entries based on aliases for example, of course). So if you plan to have more than one application running on the same instance, it's actually not a bad idea for each application to provide its local resources as part of its own files. If it's one application only, it's mostly up to you and what is easier when introducing changes - modifying the application and redeploying or modifying the server and restarting.

Check out [this pretty old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322260/which-tomcat-5-context-file-takes-precedence) for details which files are read with precedence. In your case you should be fine using either /conf/context.xml inside Tomcat or /META-INF/context.xml inside the application.

As for looking the resources up later - no, you shouldn't have to do anything extra. Either doing that directly in the code or injecting them should work fine.

What you've described on the Mac sounds funny, especially if it works on Linux. Maybe there a line ending problems with the context.xml files? Check the Tomcat log files if you haven't already, they may tell you what the problem is.