# How do you find out what context file an application on Tomcat is currently running with?

Tags: tomcat

We have an application in production, which we can see in Tomcat's Web Application Manager. What we want to know, is for a particular running application, what context.xml file is being used.

When I log onto the server, there is a context.xml in the directory:

/opt/tomcat/webapps/MY_APP/META-INF/context.xml

I'm sure that it is not the one that is being used by the application as it is currently running as it contains values for external servers that no longer exist, yet the application is working.

Is there any way to find out exactly what context.xml file is being used for a particular running Tomcat application?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Tomcat 5 context file takes precedence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322260/which-tomcat-5-context-file-takes-precedence)

Answer (score 2):

Found it, it looks like when you deploy, the current context.xml gets copied to:

/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/MY_APP.xml