# My web application is using log4j2.properties. Currently this file is in WEB-INF inside my web-app.There is ask from a client to externalize this file

Tags: logging, web-applications, log4j, log4j2

We can externalize log4j2.properties file using system property -Dlog4j2.configurationFile=<file_path>, However, there are multiple web apps deployed on the same server, So, I want to explicitly set the file path for my web app only. One way is to use the below code. However, LoggerContext is a private API that can change in minor releases. Is there any easy way (without java code) to set web application-specific (or to say external log4j2.properties per web-app) external log4j2.properties file ?

```
// import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;

LoggerContext context = (org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
File file = new File("path/to/a/different/log4j2.xml");

// this will force a reconfiguration
context.setConfigLocation(file.toURI());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add [`log4j-web`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-web) to your application, additional features specific to web applications will be present (cf. [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html)).

In your specific case your can use the `log4jConfiguration` servlet context parameter to specify the location of the config file of that particular application. How to externally specify a servlet context parameter depends on your servlet container.

For example in Tomcat you can do it in a [`context.xml` file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/322260/11748454):

```xml
<Context>
    <Parameter name="log4jConfiguration" value="/path/to/config/file" override="false"/>
    ...
</Context>
```

**Remark**: `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext` is not an internal class, it is just a class from Log4j Core (the official implementation of the Log4j API), whereas `org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggerContext` belongs to Log4j API. Unless you switch implementations from Log4j Core to another, a `LoggerContext` will always be a `core.LoggerContext`.