# JBoss - possible to mount a war on two different context paths?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, war

In JBoss, is it possible to deploy a web application on two context paths?
I'd like same war instance available on / as well as /path , so, requests like '/abc' and '/path/abc' both hit same instance of the web app.

I tried :

```
<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>web-app.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/</context-root>
    </web>
</module>

<module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>web-app.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/path</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
```

but looks like it gets deployed only on /path. All requests to '/abc' are 404s.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use Apache front-end web server with [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Since JBoss AS uses Tomcat as it's web container you can try to configure multiple context paths in context.xml.

See these links for further directions:

[Configure Tomcat application context root with context.xml](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/690/)

http://community.jboss.org/wiki/Web-AppContextConfiguration

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/context.html

[Tomcat context.xml files, is there a hiearchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318241/tomcat-context-xml-files-is-there-a-hiearchy)