# How to change the default value of context.xml in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, cross-context

I am trying to use the `crossContext` feature in Tomcat so that I need to set `<Context crossContext="true">` in the `context.xml` file located in `mypath\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\conf` folder.

However I find that every time I restart tomcat it will restore to its original value then I have to modify that again. I want to know if there is a way to avoid this so that I do not need to modify the `context.xml` file every time I restart Tomcat?

Thanks in advance!

```
<Context crossContext="true">
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```

above is the code I am using...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the the answer in this question [link] [Tomcat context.xml files, is there a hiearchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318241/tomcat-context-xml-files-is-there-a-hiearchy?rq=1)
 I figured out the way to solve this problem. Just create the `context.xml` file in the location `mypath\apache-tomcat-7.0.41\conf\Catalina\localhost` and add in `<Context crossContext="true"> </Context>` then you are done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to undeploy your web application and then re-deploy it. Tomcat is re-using the `context.xml` file you provided on initial deployment, which you can find in `CATALINA_BASE/conf/[engine]/[host]/[context].xml`. The changes you are making to your own context.xml are probably being completely ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. According to your answer and this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318241/tomcat-context-xml-files-is-there-a-hiearchy?rq=1) I find the way to solve this problem.