# Tomcat with sub folder symlink

Tags: symlink, subdirectory, tomcat7

I have a webapp that is actually a symlink named: App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and it is working fine.

Now instead of that, i want to create the folder App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and use the symlinks in the subdirectories.
I want the WEB-INF to link to one place.
And i want the Client files (/js and /css) to link to another place.
In this case i am getting 404.
[This article](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:bzjcQjPlUIAJ:www.ke-cai.net/2009/07/tomcat-symbolic-link-folders.html+tomcat+folder+symlink+context.xml&cd=10&hl=iw&ct=clnk&gl=il&source=www.google.co.il) is actually doing the same, but for some reasong i cant get it done....

Again, linking to the webapp root folder works fine.

Can you suggest a solution?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, by default Tomcat does not follow symlinks.  You may be able to configure it to do so -- see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315093/configure-symlinks-for-single-directory-in-tomcat).

Answer (score 3):

I found that using the command `sudo mount --bind olddir newdir` gets me out of trouble. If you don't have root access then this won't work for you. See `mount --help` or `man mount` for some more info on binding but it basically mounts one directory on top of another so it has the same affect as a symlink but it gets around tomcat's limitation with symlinks.

In your example, you'd probably want something like `sudo mount --bind /path/to/your/sandbox/js /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/js` and then similar for the `css` directory.