# Documentation for installing and running hadoop 2.2 on Windows

Tags: windows, hadoop

With the latest release of Hadoop 2.2 I see that the release notes mentions that this version has significant improvements for running Hadoop on Windows. I downloaded Hadoop 2.2 yesterday and I saw lot of .cmd file alon with .sh files which ensures that this version has scripts and batch files for running Hadoop on Windows environment. However while looking at the Apache Hadoop documentation I couldn't find any step-by-step instructions on how to install and run this newer version on Windows. Besides this it looks like that the newer version has YARN architecture embedded in it and the old configurations provided on some of the tutorials online may be outdated and not applicable anymore. Is there any good documentation for Hadoop 2.2 available online ? I want it specifically for running Hadoop under Windows.

Answer (score 6):

If we directly take the binary distribution of Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 release and try to run it on Microsoft Windows, then we'll encounter ERROR util.Shell: Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path.

The binary distribution of Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 release does not contain some windows native components (like winutils.exe, hadoop.dll etc). These are required (not optional) to run Hadoop on Windows.

So you need to build windows native binary distribution of hadoop from source codes following "BUILD.txt" file located inside the source distribution of hadoop. You can follow the following post as well for step by step guide with screen shot

[Build, Install, Configure and Run Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 in Microsoft Windows OS](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/38/build-install-configure-run-apache-hadoop-2.2.0-microsoft-windows-os)

Answer (score 0):

i was searching for the same thing. I found hortonworks interesteing. They dedicated themselves to installing hadoop on windows. I tried it out, but i still get errors on launching all the services. The only advice i have received in their forum was to delete everything installed and reinstall the whole stuff. I haven't done that yet.

As a prerequesite, you will need to have your windows running on 64 bit.

Try that out and let me know if it worked on your site. There IS A STEP-TO-STEP guide on the hortonworks website.

Cheers Jan

Comment: [Instructions here](http://hortonworks.com/blog/install-hadoop-windows-hortonworks-data-platform-2-0/). Big gotcha to watch out for: Make sure Java is installed to a path that doesn't have spaces in it.