# Accessing Symbolic links inside the tomcat aliases

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

In  My application's context.xml inside meta-inf,

I have created aliases as shown below.

```
<Context aliases="/a=/d/e/a"/>
```

the path `/d/e/a` is a shared mount path which is outside of the web application.

Now the problem is when i try to access a below content

`/d/e/a/h/zzz.pdf`, am getting 404 error. the reason is h is a symbolic link in the mount which points to the another path say `/i/j/k` in the mount.

So how to access the folders having symbolic links inside the tomcat aliases?

Answer (score 1):

See:
[Configure Symlinks for single directory in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315093/configure-symlinks-for-single-directory-in-tomcat)

http://isocra.com/2008/01/following-symbolic-links-in-tomcat/