# View Tomcat log files in a browser

Tags: tomcat, logging, browser

I need to somehow expose the Tomcat log files to a browser. I know that is not secure, but that's what's being requested.

I have considered making a hard link from the log location, such as `tomcat/webapps/ROOT/html/catalina.out` -> `mydir/logs/catalina.out`, but I don't think that's a good solution (even though it does work). Is there an established way of exposing Tomcat log files to a browser?

Answer (score 23):

This modification to distribution configurations will expose Tomcat logs over HTTP via the services of the Tomcat DefaultServlet. Confirmed with Tomcat distributions of 7.0.56, 8.0.24.

*For purposes of this example, the canonical Tomcat distribution is given to be unpacked to /opt/tomcat.*

In `/opt/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost` create the file `logs.xml` with this content:

> <Context override="true" docBase="/opt/tomcat/logs" path="/logs" />

Restart Tomcat. Browse to a log file you know is there, e.g.

- localhost:8080/**logs**/catalina.out

If you additionally desire to be able to browse the listing of logs, suggest this additional configuration change.

Edit `/opt/tomcat/conf/web.xml`. Where the `listings` parameter is configured, turn it on by setting its value to `true`:

> ...
>      <servlet>
>   ...
>          <init-param>
>              <param-name>listings</param-name>
>              <param-value>**true**</param-value>
>          </init-param>
>   ...

Restart your tomcat for changes to take effect. Expect to see a list of log files as clickable links when conducting this test in a browser

- localhost:8080/**logs**/

These settings are likely not desirable for some production environments due to either security or performance/resource usage concerns.

In some senses a rephrasing of this item:
[Simplest way to serve static data from outside the application server in a Java web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812244/simplest-way-to-serve-static-data-from-outside-the-application-server-in-a-java)

Learn more (at the ragged edges of this question)

- [Configure Symlinks for single directory in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315093/configure-symlinks-for-single-directory-in-tomcat)
- [How to config Tomcat to serve images from an external folder outside webapps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417658/how-to-config-tomcat-to-serve-images-from-an-external-folder-outside-webapps)

And the ever helpful docs

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html
- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html

Comment: Nota bene: The name of logs.xml is flexible. As long as it is consistent with the defined path parameter.

Comment: The same notes apply to the Tomcat 8.x series.

Comment: I can confirm that it also works for 9.x series. Really good comment! Thank you!