# Spring: direct access and serve images outside of the website directory

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and Tomcat 8.0.36 for my web application. I have an image directory to access, but it is outside the website directory. Here is what I have, but it seems not working:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/uploads/v1/**" location="Z:/uploads/v1/" />
```

The website is located at:

```
E:\website\tomcat\webapps\mysite
```

Does Spring support such access? The site runs on Windows. I am hoping that

http://mysite/uploads/v1/image.jpg would be served from Z:/uploads/v1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read some posts at SO about similar questions, such as this one:

[Configure Symlinks for single directory in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315093/configure-symlinks-for-single-directory-in-tomcat)

The interesting thing is that I did not use context or something. I simply created a symbolic link under /site/uploads by using this command:

```
mklink /D v1 Z:\uploads\v1
```

I also used the following in spring:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/uploads/v1/**" location="/uploads/v1/" />
```